# Does Istio recommend using Roles and ClusterRoles?

Tags: kubernetes, istio, rbac

I am trying to setup my Helm chart to be able to deploy a `VirtualService`.  My deploy user has the `Edit` ClusterRole bound to it.  But I realized that because Istio is not part of the core Kubernetes distro, the `Edit` ClusterRole does not have permissions to add a `VirtualService` (or even look at them).

I can, of course, make my own Roles and ClusterRoles if needed.  But I figured I would see if Istio has a recommended Role or ClusterRole for that.

But all the docs that I can find for Istio Roles and ClusterRoles are for old versions of Istio.

**Does Istio not recommend using Roles and ClusterRoles anymore?  If not, what do they recommend?  If they do, where are the docs for it?**

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using these ClusterRoles.  They merge with the standard Kubernetes roles of admin, edit and view.  (My edit role only allows access to the VirtualService because that fit my situtation.)

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:  
  name: istio-admin
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups: ["config.istio.io", "networking.istio.io", "rbac.istio.io", "authentication.istio.io", "security.istio.io"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["*"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:  
  name: istio-edit
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups: ["config.istio.io", "networking.istio.io", "rbac.istio.io", "authentication.istio.io", "security.istio.io"]
  resources: ["virtualservices"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:  
  name: istio-view
  labels:
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
rules:
- apiGroups: ["config.istio.io", "networking.istio.io", "rbac.istio.io", "authentication.istio.io", "security.istio.io"]
  resources: ["*"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
```

Comment: Hi @Vaccano ! As far as I know, these rules will be added in the aggregated ClusterRoles only after API server restart. Do you know some way to force the update without the API server restart? Thanks!